# GeoServer not showing values for NetCDF 0/1 file

Tags: geoserver, netcdf, colormap

I have a simple NetCDF file consisting in 4 dimensions (fulmini, lat, lon, time - being the latter the result of a selection of all the data from a certain time), and I'm trying to load it in GeoServer to have it as a WMS.

I manage to download the appropriate plugin and load the data correctly. Anyway, I'm having problems with the styling and the related SLD file. At first, using type="intervals", I only saw a colored square. Changing to type="values" I manage to correctly show data with 0 but not 1. 1 values are not rendered, being transparent in my viewer.

I checked in Python my values, finding that I only have 0 and 1

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
file_path = '########.nc'
variable_name = 'fulmini'
ds = xr.open_dataset(file_path)
variable = ds[variable_name]
unique_values = np.unique(variable.values)
print("Unique values:", unique_values)

Unique values: [0 1]
```

What can it be the problem and its solution?

Comment: what does your SLD look like?